# Elixir: Set cookie and hostname for release created using mix escript.build

Tags: elixir

When running iex interactively, one can use

```
iex --cookie <cookie> --name <hostname>
```

How do I set the same values for `cookie` and `name` when running an executable created using `mix escript.build`?

I figured out that I need to create a `vm.args` file with the following contents

```
## Name of the node
-name name@host

## Cookie for distributed erlang
-setcookie cookie
```

So I created a `vm.args` file in the same directory as the executable file. But when I print `Node.self()`, I get `:nonode@nohost`.

So where do I store `vm.args` so that it is read by the executable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know, `vm.args` is not read by escripts. You have (at least) 2 options:

1. Set these values in `emu_args` key passed to `escript` in `project/0` in `mix.exs`:

   ```
   def project do
     [app: :m,
      ...,
      escript: [main_module: M, emu_args: ["-name foo@bar -setcookie baz"]]]
   end
   ```
2. Parse the CLI arguments and set the values in your `main` function:

   ```
   defmodule M do
     def main([name, cookie]) do
       Node.start String.to_atom(name)
       Node.set_cookie String.to_atom(cookie)
       IO.inspect {Node.self, Node.get_cookie}
     end
   end
   ```

   ```
   $ mix escript.build
   $ ./m foo@bar baz
   {:foo@bar, :baz}
   ```

Comment: There is also the env variable ERL_AFLAGS in http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html, but I didn't have the time to see if it could solve this problem.

Comment: @FredtheMagicWonderDog that works! Would you like to post an answer? That's a better solution as you don't have to change any code.

Comment: Go ahead, you did the hard work of verifying that it actually works.